# Run aapt inside a shell script to dump the permissions of all apk files under a directory?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, aapt

I need to dump all info of huge number of apk files under a directory. For each apk file I need to get package name & permissions! I tried the code below but it did not work!

```
for file in *; do 
    aapt dump permissions $file
done
```

I can run the command in the terminal but can not run aapt inside a shell script! I get this error: "command not found"! what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you can use following command : -

```
find ./ -name "*.apk" -exec aapt dump permissions {} \;
```

Here *.apk (Files name pattern) needs to be verified according to requirement.

Thanks